# py2exe + Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, py2exe

We were compiling Django with py2exe until the version 1.3. From Django 1.4, the way to find the commands changed and manage.exe doesn't show any commands as it is trying to find .py files and py2exe just has .pyc files. I have tried to hack the way that Django uses to find the commands but the result was negative as well. Also, I tried to modify manage.py to call a command depending on the arguments passed but the functions that exist in Django use .py files as well.

Did anyone manage to do it?